# Need to create a printable table that organizes results handled by a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, html, printing

I have written a program using HTML and JavaScript that calculates the price of a sliding door for a metal roofing companies website. When the user puts in values such as height and width the numbers are ran through a script and it outputs results such as price, and qty of tools needed. I want to create a page that displays these results neatly and can be printed by the user. I have tries using PHP but this has proven difficult. What is the easiest way to make this work?

```
<tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td>' .$trackResult. '&acute;<br />' .$trackResultOne. '&acute;<br />' .$trackResultTwo. '&acute;</td>
</tr>
```

This is where I am having trouble, this table is being echoed in a PHP page. Sometimes $trackResultOne and Two do not have values and I do not want them to echo. For now the table is simply showing like this...

Track - 1 - 10'  <

Comment: Please post some code, it does wonders when trying to help out. Are you using forms? If so, I'd personally go with PHP to show the user input.

Comment: I am currently using PHP to handle it, I will edit the post to show where I am having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to echo the users input on another page. This easily done using forms and PHP.

form.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="formname" action="script.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="trackResult" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="trackResultOne" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="trackResultTwo" /><br/>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
<?php
$trackResult = $_POST['trackResult'];
$trackResultOne = $_POST['trackResultOne'];
$trackResultTwo = $_POST['trackResultTwo'];
.
.
.
?>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Track</td>
<td><?php echo $trackResult."&acute;<br/>";
    if($trackResultOne != NULL){ echo $trackResultOne."&acute;<br/>";
    if($trackResultTwo != NULL){ echo $trackResultTwo."&acute;";
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you add in more `input` fields in your HTML, make sure to set the variables for those fields in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr>
     <td>Track</td>
     <td>' .$trackResult. '&acute';

    if ($trackResultOne != NULL) {

    <br /> .$trackResultOne. '&acute;'

    }

if ($trackResultOne != NULL) {

    <br />.$trackResultTwo. '&acute;'

    }

    </td>
    </tr>
```

Something like that I guess. Check if the value is not NULL, then print